# jquery change array to string

Tags: jquery, arrays, string, save

using this little jquery i am able to save the data-id of the clicked list-element in an input-hidden-field:

(Important: Only one data-id can be saved in this input-hidden-field, if you click next element, this hidden-field gets updated.)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ui-selectable :not([data-id=""])').click(function() {
        $('.ui-selectable .selected:not([data-id=""])').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        $(this).parent().trigger('update');
    });

    $('.ui-selectable').on('update', function() {
        data = [];
        $(':not([data-id=""]).selected', this).each(function() {
            data.push( $(this).data('id') );
        });
    });
});
```

For now its saved in an array as you can see in:

```
data = [];
```

But i need to save it in a string, anybody could help with it?

Comment: Maybe call `JSON.stringify` on the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method will give you a comma separated string of your array.

Comment: This is a bad way to serialize arrays.  If any strings within the array had a comma, you'd run into problems deserializing the string later.  This is, of course, not always a problem if you know what type of data is in your array, but perhaps not the best habit to get into.

Answer (score 2):

You can change that array into a string by using `JSON.stringify`,

Try this,

```
JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: which line do i have to put it? after i declared the array?

Comment: @user3080627 This will convert the array `data` into a string. So you can call it after filling your array.

Comment: Some browsers don't support the JSON object.  For more browser compatibility, you can just use the Array object's native `toString()` method.  That is `data.toString()`.

Comment: @TNguyen Can you name some of them.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: lots, and not even that long ago! http://caniuse.com/#search=JSON